# Is it mysql bug or expected behavior?

Tags: mysql, subquery

mysql 5.7.33 
iso level : read committed 
autocommit : off

session 1:
create table t1(tid int not null,tname varchar(32) null);
create table t2(tid int primary key not null, tname varchar(32) null);
insert into t1 values(1,'1'),(2,'2'),(3,'3'),(4,'4');
insert into t2 values(1,'1'),(2,'2'),(3,'3'),(4,'4');
commit;
set autocommit=0;
delete from t1
where tid in(
select tid from t2
where tname is not null
)
and tname is null
;
without commit

then open another session(we call it session 2),
execute:
update t2 set tname = null;
the update statement is blocked by session 1.

And session 2 is also blocked in mysql 8.0.25.

Answer (score 0):

i run it in 8.0.20,but it is also blocked in session2

session1

```sql
select version();
drop table if exists t1;
drop table if exists t2;

set session transaction isolation level read committed;
SELECT @@transaction_isolation;

create table t1(tid int not null,tname varchar(32) null);
create table t2(tid int primary key not null, tname varchar(32) null);
insert into t1 values(1,'1'),(2,'2'),(3,'3'),(4,'4');
insert into t2 values(1,'1'),(2,'2'),(3,'3'),(4,'4');
commit;
set autocommit=0;
delete from t1 where tid in( select tid from t2 where tname is not null ) and tname is null ;

#commit;
```

session2

```sql
set session transaction isolation level read committed;
SELECT @@transaction_isolation;

update t2 set tname = null;
```

Is the test method different?

Comment: test again, mysql 8.0.25, session 2 also blocked...